# Pinvoke C#: delegated function cause crash

Tags: c#, delegates, pinvoke, access-violation

I'm trying to use the function below to map another function to be called when data arrives.
the C++ function creates a new thread in which my function will be called. it works for a few seconds but then i get an error :(i've turned  "enable unmanaged code debugging to see this error")
`Unhandled exception at 0x7725158e in threadTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.`

If I remove the `IntPtr frameData` from the delegated function everything works fine, therefore i suspect there is something i should do to the declaration of the delegate class to avoid this from happening.

C# code:

```
public delegate void HandlerFunction(IntPtr frameData);

[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll")]
public extern static int Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(HandlerFunction function);


-----
public class myClass
{
    static HandlerFunction myFunction = new HandlerFunction(threadFunction);
    public myClass()
    {
        Cortex.Cortex_SetDataHandlerFunc(myFunction);
    }

    private static void threadFunction(IntPtr FrameData)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect this is just a calling convention problem. Your C++ code assumes cdecl, but the C# code assumes stdcall. Simply specify cdecl in the P/Invoke and you should be golden.

Comment: I have the same problem but i don't understand what is `cdecl` and `stdcall` can you please explain?

Comment: Why would you need me to explain this when there are countless articles online that do so? The ability to do basic research online is a pre-requisite for life as a programmer.